# How to fix TS2081 && TS2087 errors in TypeScript 0.9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Just need to fix this errors. If it helps this app uses AngularJS. TypeScript version is 0.9.0.0

> > /path/app/scripts/Application.ts(22,13):
> >     error TS2081: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
> >     /path/app/scripts/Application.ts(22,13):
> >     error TS2087: Could not select overload for 'call' expression.

Application.ts

```
import controllers = module("scripts/Controllers"); 
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'templates-main']);  
app.controller(controllers.data);
```

22,13 points to `app.controller(controllers.data);`

Module "scripts/Controllers"

```
export var data = {
  "MainCtrl": ($scope) => {
    $scope.login = ()=> {
      console.log('do something');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Try using `(<any> app).controller(controllers.data);`. This is a bit hacky but should at least suppress the error message.

Comment: Thanks, you've just make me so happy. Post any answer and I'll give you some reps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
(<any> app).controller(controllers.data);
```

The statement `<Type> Variable` *"converts"* (in the sense of changing the assumed type by TypeScript) the variable to the given type.

And since we convert it to the *any* type, TypeScript lets us do anything we want with it.

If you want to *fix* the real cause, you could edit the TypeScript definition file you're using.